# How create a handler error component with ErrorBoundary and componentDidCatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found myself trying to make an error handler with ErrorBoundary, however after a couple of days and a lot of patience I managed to capture the error and save the error in the database by calling an API in the back-end.

NOTE: if you have a better solution please comment this post.

First: Create your ErrorBoundary component as the [ReactJs documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html) says except for a couple of modifications that add

Once you enter the ComponentDidCatch the ErrorBoundary sends directly to the render, it does not go through another lifecycle of React, then, we created another intermediate component in which to call the API and be able to use the lifecycles quietly, but we added a callback method to notify the errorBoundary that the error was already notified and redirect the view of home or whatever your primary view.

first: my Errorboundary component:

```
 /**
 * @desc Dependencias
 */
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

/**
 * @desc Acciones
 */
import { saveError } from '../../actions/ErrorsActions';

/**
 * @desc Componentes
 */
import Modal from '../Modal/ModalContainer';
import ErrorMessage from './errorMesage';

class ErrorBoundary extends Component {

  /**
   * @desc Constructor del componente.
   * 
   * @param { Object } props 
   * 
   * @return { Void }
   */
  constructor(props) {

    super( props );

    // Estado incial.
    this.state = { 

      // Se encontro un error.
      foundError: {
        display : false,
        message: null
      }
    };
  }

  /**
   * @desc Ciclo de vida: Comienzo del montado del componente.
   * 
   * @return { void }
   */
  componentDidMount(){

    // Global catch of unhandled Promise rejections:
    global.onunhandledrejection = error => {  

      // Warning: when running in "remote debug" mode (JS environment is Chrome browser),
      // this handler is called a second time by Bluebird with a custom "dom-event".
      // We need to filter this case out:
      if (error instanceof Error) {

        // Alias
        let { foundError } = this.state;

        // Indice del split al stack.
        let index = error.stack.indexOf(".");

        // Asignamos el stack
        foundError.display = true;
        foundError.message = error.stack.substring( 0, index )
                                        .trim()
                                        .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");

        // Actualizamos el estado con el error.
        this.setState({ foundError })        

      }
    };
  }

  /**
   * @desc Detecta los errores no manipulados de la aplicación.
   * 
   * @param { Object } error 
   * @param { Object } info 
   * 
   * @return { Void }
   */
  componentDidCatch( error, info) {

    // Alias
    let { foundError } = this.state;

    // Indice del split al stack.
    let index = info.componentStack.indexOf("(");

    // Mensaje del error
    let message = error.message + " - " + info.componentStack.substring( 0, index ).trim();

    // Asignamos el stack
    foundError.display = true;
    foundError.message = message;

    // Actualizamos el estado con el error.
    this.setState({ foundError })

  }

  /**
   * @desc 
   * 
   * @return { void }
   */
  async closeModal(){

    // `enter code here`Alias
    let { foundError } = this.state;

    // Reiniciamos el estado del error.
    foundError.display = false;
    foundError.message = null;

    // Actualizamos el estado
    await this.setStateAsync({ foundError });

  }

  /**
   * @desc Renderiza el componente.
   * 
   * @return { * }
   */
  render() {

    // Alias
    let { language, children } = this.props;
    let { foundError } = this.state;

    // Validamos si se debe mostrar el modal de crash.
    if( !foundError.display )
      return children;
    else
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return ( <ErrorMessage { ...this.props }
                             onClose={ () => this.closeModal() }
                             stack={ foundError.stack } 
                             message={ foundError.message } /> );
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

In the render we check if there was an error, if so, we call our as an error component, if not, we return the children.

in the ErrorMessage Component:

```
/**
 * @desc Dependencias
 */
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

/**
 * @desc Lenguaje
 */
import Lenguaje from '../../lenguage/es-ar.json';

/**
 * @desc Acciones
 */
import { saveError } from '../../actions/ErrorsActions';

/**
 * @desc Componentes
 */
import Modal from '../Modal/ModalContainer';

class ErrorMeesage extends Component {


  /**
   * @desc Constructor del componente.
   * 
   * @param { Object } props 
   * 
   * @return { Void }
   */
  constructor(props) {

    super( props );

    this.state = {

      // Modal de crash.
      modalCrash: {
        display: true,
        type: 'crash',
        content: {
          title: '',
          body: '',
        }
      }

    }

  }

  componentDidMount(){

    // Lanzamos el almacenamiento del stack.
    this.saveAudit();

  }

  /**
    * @desc Permite el acceso asincronico al setState de react.
    *
    * @param { Object } state
    * 
    * @return { Promise }
  */
  setStateAsync( state ){
   return new Promise( resolve => this.setState( state,  () => {
     resolve()
    }))
  }

  /**
   * @desc Envia para almacenar el stack de errores.
   * 
   * @return { Promise<void> }
   */
  async saveAudit(){

    // Alias
    let { history, country, message } = this.props;

    // Datos.
    let data = {
      type: 'WEB',
      subtype: 'ERROR',
      details: message
    };

    // Solicitamos el guardado del error.
    let response =  saveError( country, data );

    // Esperamos la solicitud se cumpla. 
    response.payload = await response.payload;

    // Datos del modal.
    let title       = Lenguaje && Lenguaje.WAS_AN_ERROR,
        body        = Lenguaje.GENERAL_ERROR_CODE.replace('{0}', response.payload.data ),
        callback    = async () => {

          await this.hideModalCrash();

          // Redirección.
          history.push('/home');

        };

    // Mostramos el modal de crash.
    await this.showModalCrash( title, body, callback ); 

  }

  /**
  * Muestra el modal de error.
  * 
  * @param { String } title
  * @param { String } body
  * 
  * @return { Promise<Boolean> }
  */
  async showModalCrash( title = '', body = '', callback = null){

  // Alias
  let { modalCrash } = this.state;

  try{

    // Asignamos los valores al modal.
    modalCrash.display = true;
    modalCrash.content.title = title; 
    modalCrash.content.body = body;
    modalCrash.callback = typeof callback === "function" && callback;

    // Actualizamos el estado interno.
    this.setState({ modalCrash });

    return true;

  }catch( error ){

    return false;

  }

  }

  /**
  * Oculta el modal de error.
  * 
  * @return { Promise<Boolean> }
  */
  async hideModalCrash(){

    // Alias
    let { modalCrash } = this.state;

    try{

      // Limpiamos el modal de eliminación.
      modalCrash.display = false;
      modalCrash.content.title = '';
      modalCrash.content.body = '';

      // Actualizamos el estado.
      await this.setStateAsync({ modalCrash });

      // El modal fue ocultado.
      await this.props.onClose();

      return true;

    }catch( error ){

      return false;

    }

  }

  /**
   * @desc Renderiza el componente.
   * 
   * @return { * }
   */
  render() {

    // Alias
    let { modalCrash } = this.state;
    let { language } = this.props;

    return(<Modal  type="crash"
                    isWrapper 
                    dataModal={ modalCrash } 
                    language={ language }
                    handleClick={ () => typeof modalCrash.callback === "function" && modalCrash.callback() } />);

  }

}
export default ErrorMessage;
```

in the ErrorMessage component, we call the API to save the error, we show a modal to notify the user and then in the HideCrashModal we have a method that notifies the ErrorBoundary that the error was notified: await this.props.onClose ();

an example of how to implement this component:

```
  <Route path="/home"    render= { props => 
            <ErrorBoundary { ...this.props }> 
              <Welcome history={ props.history } dispatch={ props.dispatch } />  
            </ErrorBoundary>
            } />
```

Now, the ComponentDidCatch cannot capture errors in asynchronous code, however we replace the promises with those of BlueBird and we can use a method of capturing these errors in our ErrorBoundary so that we have a centralized error point so we add the global.onunhandlerrejection in the ComponentDidMount lifecycle in this way if the BlueBird error handler detects an error in some promise it will take it in our ErrorBoundary.

Comment: Are you asking for a review?

Comment: yes, and also if someone does not know how to use the componentDidCatch and catch asynchronous code errors, I show you how I could solve it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you separate this into a question and an answer, you can "self answer" it and get credit. Right now as a code review request it is likely to be seen as off topic. There is a separate site in the Stack Exchange network for code reviews, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but you will want to read their tour before using that site.